# android how to fill seachview suggestion list with cursor

Tags: android

I have a seachview in my main activity which extends fragmentactivity. My cursor object contains the correct search result. How can I dynamically inflate the suggestion list based on the search result[image]? now it's just an empty list.

Comment: "My cursor object contains the correct search result" what cursor object?

Comment: Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database.getReadableDatabase(), null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

Comment: when do you call `query()` method?

Comment: the seachview is associated with a ContentProvider.  the query method is called whenever search keyword changes

Comment: so you are using setOnQueryTextListener(SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener), right?

Comment: no, I have  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" /> in my main activity intent filter

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671954/android-prevent-text-truncation-in-searchview-suggestions

Comment: thanks a lot.I solved it. I was missing some code. after I added setProjectionMap()method. it worked